# 3.5 inch tft display not displaying but touch working on a rpi 0 w

Tags: display

I got a 3.5 inch TFT display which has touch, I connected it to my Raspberry Pi Zero W with GPIO pins.

I installed the drivers (LCD35-show) from the website and it took a reboot. Once reboot is completed a white screen appears and then a blank screen appears but it is lit.

The touch screen works but I don't see anything on my screen except for a blank lit screen.

Any help would be appreciated. I need it fixed urgently, thanks!!!!

Comment: how do you know that the touch panel works?

Comment: Check the wiring. And if you have a reference to a guide, website include the link!

Comment: @jsotola I used a vnc viewer and when I touched the display , it moves on VNC

Comment: @MatsK http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display , I connected it like this : https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/interfacing-tft-lcd-display-with-raspberry-pi-zero-w

Comment: Edit your answer and add that info please.